# Pause execution in method until SelectionChanged event from ListView is raised

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10-universal

I have a windows 10 uwp app in C#. In one method, I check a list of strings. If I only have one item in my list, we are good. However, if I have more than one item, I want to popup a ListView so the user can select the one string from the multiples. When they select one, the ListView_SelectionChanged event is raised and I can get the selected string. However, that is in a different method/event from the caller obviously.

The issue is, I want the calling method to pause execution and wait until the user selects a string from the ListView. After, they select one, I need to continue execution in the caller. I know this was done with a while loop and a flag in the past but this is blocking. I don't necessarily care if it blocks but with async/await and other new framework features, I am sure there is a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: You simply can't pause execution in an event handler which has a void signature. Since you can't change it to a task, it  doesn't support the async flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I accidentally asked this same question, in a different way twice. For that I apologize. I think I was still searching around for a solution to this problem with no answer that was working and I posted again.

That said, I was able to finally come up with a solution that works for me and I wanted to share it. I already answered it on my other question so here is the link to it.

[My answer on the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43098928/5902558)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you need non-blocking solution then you need to implement **async/await**. 
When execution encounters await keyword it will return control to the caller. After the user selects values from the ListView control resumes on await operator.

More information on [Asynchronous Programming with async and await (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx).